# cd failing git hooks

Tags: git, github, githooks

when I try to CD into particular folder, it's getting stuck after "unset done". Not sure why .tried unsetting GIT_DIR, env -i. But no hope!

```
branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
command="ansible-playbook -i hosts tasks/git_pull.yml --extra-vars='host=" 
command=$command$branch"'"
echo $command >> gitpush2.txt
unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
echo "enter /home/hari/code/ansible/git/" >> gitpush2.txt 
echo "unset" >> gitpush2.txt
unset GIT_DIR
echo "unset done" >> gitpush2.txt
cd /home/hari/code/ansible/git/ 
echo "got in" >> gitpush2.txt
unset GIT_DIR
echo "execute" >> gitpush2.txt
env -i eval $command >> gitpush3.txt
echo "done " >> gitpush2.txt
```

Comment: Try using `cd directory || return`. Works better for scripts...

Comment: tried this. Its not working.